# Interpretation of jmc flight recorder data parked threads

Tags: jmc, jfr

I am trying to interpret a jmc flight recording data. Seeing a definite number of threads all basically in parked state. What does this signify?
Also attached is the CPU load during the time. It seems that JVM CPU is lot lesser than machine CPU which per the blog here seems to indicate a native methods taking too long (Threads in this case ?).

[image: Thread Graph]

[image: CPU load]

[image: events stacktrace]
All this analysis is to pinpoint latency reasons of an app.

Comment: The machine total CPU, or rather the part of it that are above the JVM parts of the graph, indicate that other processes are using CPU. If you would see a lot of grey, that could potentially be native code in your JVM process that needed to run in kernel space.

Comment: I know way to little about both XNIO and thread pools/park in general, but all the parked threads, couldn't it be just that the thread pool has nothing to do?

Comment: thread pool actually had lot to do. It just seems (atleast from the graphic) they just wouldnt budge.